# Why nginx doesn't know PHP on os X and starts downloading it?

Tags: nginx, mac-osx, php-fpm

I have installed nginx, php-fpm and php56 on `OS X EL CAPITAN`. I used `ps` command to check whether nginx and fpm is running or not.

I have added the below code block to `server` block in nginX:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
```

nginX listen on `8080` and fpm on `9000`. I used `lsof` command to check that:

```
php-fpm   22903   root    0u  IPv4 0x5a9bc9209264e227      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm   22904     fc    0u  IPv4 0x5a9bc9209264e227      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
nginx     22931     fc    6u  IPv4 0x5a9bc9208c304cc7      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
nginx     22932     fc    6u  IPv4 0x5a9bc9208c304cc7      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

Any clue about the issue why nginx downloads php files rather than interpreting them?

**EDIT1:**
Full nginX configuration:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /usr/local/var/www/;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
    include servers/*;
```

The URL I have fetched is: `http://localhost:8080/info.php`

Does anyone has any clue about this issue? I went on every question in `stackoverflow` with no success:

```
http://serverfault.com/questions/563285/nginx-with-php-fpm-downloading-php-files-rather-than-executing-them-on-mac-os-x?rq=1

http://serverfault.com/questions/412079/nginx-php-fpm-php-file-not-found-cant-figure-out-why?rq=1
```

Comment: Please show your full configuration and what is the exact URL you are fetching when PHP file is downloaded.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I have added the nginX full configuration file in the EDIT section, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I've just changed the below line:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
```

**TO:**

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

It works now.